# Error while compiling hello_world in windows

Tags: windows, v8

i've got this error [error image](http://www.freeimagehosting.net/k1uyl) when trying to compile the hello_world example on getting started of v8 section [get started google v8](https://developers.google.com/v8/get_started). I built it using arm architecture. I'm using visual studio build scheme. I've followed instruction on google developer page, but still got this error.

Need solution for this, please.

Comment: 1) Gcc uses .a files, not .lib (they're generally MS-built static libraries) 2) You didn't link the v8 library. There's the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Instructions on Google V8 website explain how to compile v8 using Microsofr Visual Studio.
As a result you get DLL and LIB files. LIB files are only recognized by Microsoft compilers.

If you want to use GCC/CLANG for developing v8 application you should link directly against DLL file. If you are using older version of GCC that cannot link directly against DLL, you need to convert DLL to .a file.